# Why do I keep getting the wrong date/time when converting from a UTC timestamp?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date, utc

I am trying to make a weather forecast app, and I am given a UTC timestamp from the api: OpenWeatherMap. I convert it into a date by creating a Date object. For example, for the UTC time stamp 1589220000, the time in UTC is May 11, 6 PM. I do this conversion, and I always get May 11, 2 PM. Coincidentally, I do live in a place where the time is 4 hours behind UTC, but when I tested my app using fake gps location changers, I still got May 11, 2PM. This shows that Android is not creating a calendar based on my current location, because Dubai's time zone is not 4 hours behind as an example.

Heres my code:

```
public String convertDate(long unixTimeStamp) throws ParseException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d, h:mm aaa");
        Date date = new Date(unixTimeStamp*1000 );
        String nowDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        return nowDate;
    }
```

Comment: Which API level are you targeting? Anyways, you should use classes from the `java.time` package. You can then simply use `Instant.ofEpochSecond` to get an `Instant`, which can then be converted to an `OffsetDateTime`, which then can be formatted using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat`, so you will get the JVM's default time zone:

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/zGL9qB)

Comment: Hey, this actually worked, thank you for the demo. I manually set the time zone like you did and it works. One more question further on. I can get weather data from many cities around the world, and this api gives a time zone offset in seconds either negative or positive. Would that mean I can take the UTC time, and add the offset seconds * 1000 to get that city's local time? i.e my place is 4 hours behind, and api gives me -14400 seconds. Can i do (Timestamp * 1000L + offset_seconds * 1000L) ?

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a Favor and use `java.time.*` and not `Date`/`SimpleDateFormat`.

If you cannot use API 26/Gradle 4.x or above (and therefore have access to Java 8), then use, until you can, https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ which you can use on Android via Jake Wharton's adaptation: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

To convert an instant of time since epoch you do:

```
    val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds)

    val result = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime() //for example
```

There are plenty of methods to play around with.

Don't forget to Initialize the library for the TimeZone databases to be loaded. In your `Application` class, add this to `onCreate()`:

```
    AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
```

To format your date, you can continue with the "result" above:

```
val result = ...
result.format(DateTimeFormatter...)
```

There are plenty of DateTimeFormatter helper functions, read the documentation, it's quite easy to use.

One of them is `ofPattern(...)`:

```
DateTimeFormatter
   .ofPattern("EEEE, MMM d, h:mm aaa")
   .withLocale(Locale.US) // you can use systemDefault or chose another
```

The sky, is the limit.

Comment: Good and helpful answer. Since the questioner has got a timestamp in seconds (not milliseconds), [`Instant.ofEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond(long)) is even more useful.